# When to use azure functions vs azure durable functions when doing ETL at regular interval

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I need to run a job at regular 5 min interval where the we will call a web service to get data then transform the data and update the database.

For such scenario should is it best to use azure functions or azure durable functions.

Comment: Reading the tags... azure durable is stateful. The other is not. Do you need to preserve state between calls?

Comment: Have you ever considered azure data factory?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I would say yes task1 send web service request, task 2 transform task 3 write to DB

Comment: @PeterBons I will have a look at data factory thanks for the suggestion but does data factory support cron jobs and call web service quests?

Comment: It supports web services and schedules

Comment: It doesn't particularly support cron jobs and it supports web services but most integration tools do to some extent. You don't need any of these tools though. If you have a server running a cron job then that server can also run a script that calls a web service, loads it into a DB and transforms it.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid when you say it do you mean azure function or azure data factory i am trying to move away from running cron jobs a server due to reliability issues

Comment: That's not what you explained in your original post. Can you edit your post and make it clear that you do not want to use a cron job at all. In that case I suggest you first try data factory. Here is an example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest . It really depends on your coding background. You could also use Azure Automation and Powershell or yes you could use azure functions if you'd rather code something in C#

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid do what to setup a cron job but not on a IaaS server and schedule it as a task. that is why I was thinking of using Azure Functions

Comment: We are going around in circles now, _and_ you did not edit your question. Azure Functions, Azure Data Factory and Azure Automation are all non-IaaS solutions that you can use to replace a cron job that peforms data activities. The script that is called by the existing cron job - what is it written in? You'll need to rewrite it in powershell (for Azure Automation) or C# or JavaScript (for Azure Functions)